# How can I share a package between Node and React when they have separate dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I made a package for Error Logging that works on Node and I'd like to use it in my React projects as well.

However, the error logging requires a different NPM Library for React.

How can I select which Library I want to use according to whether my package is installed for a React project or for a Node project? Is this possible at all?

I tried checking if the window object is available, and if so requiring the library React uses, if not requiring the Node library.

After importing this package into a React project however it fails the build because it complains about not being able to use the Node package which doesn't work for React.

Code example:

```
 if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const Raven = require('raven-js');
      Raven.config(this.SENTRY_KEY).install();
 } else {
      const Sentry = require('@sentry/node');
      Sentry.init({
          dsn: this.SENTRY_KEY,
    });
}
```

I'd like to be able to use this package for both Node and React.

Edit - To make it clear, the reason it's giving issues is because one of the dependencies is @sentry/node and that fails the React build. 
It'd be nice if there was some way to not install certain dependencies according to environment.

Comment: I always thought it would be trivial, just as building for development / production is easy (`NODE_ENV === "production" ? require("a") : require("b")`), yet my search did not yield anything useful ... I'm curious for an answer and I'm open to raise a bounty.

Comment: if window is undefined, you should get @sentry/node. I think your conditions is wrong.
Furthermore, I'd recommend publishing two different packages as react can run in a node environment with ssr. And it can cause unexpected behaviour now or in the future

Comment: You could use a forced webpack alais within the code. You always call `@sentry/node` but if webpack is used alais it to point to `raven-js`